# Kendo-Angular grid display a hyperlink only if cell value is greater than zero

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with hyperlink to cell values as below,

[image]

on clicking the hyperlink it routes to different page, based on different scenarios

```
       <kendo-grid-column title="Test3" field="testCount"
            [minResizableWidth]="30" [width]='gridColumnWidth' [filterable]="false" [sortable]="false">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                    (click)="goToPage(test3)"
                    class="href-color">
                    {{dataItem.testCount}}</a>
            </ng-template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

How can I avoid the hyperlink on the cell with count as zero, since it directs to no data grid in another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Us an ngIf to conditionally show the anchor tag:

```html
<a *ngIf="dataItem.testCount > 0; else noHyperlink"
   href="javascript:void(0)"
   (click)="goToPage(test3)"
   class="href-color">
   {{dataItem.testCount}}</a>
<ng-template #noHyperlink>0</ng-template>
```